# Export mathematical expressions for further reuse

Tags: export, import

I am dealing with a program with Mathematica where I compute expressions that take a very long time to compute. I need these results for further computation and/or display. I would like not to have to redo all the computations all the time, so save the results in files that can be imported again, without computation. But I need Mathematica to be able to read the expressions as mathematical expressions again, not just as text files.

For example, if I export the expression `GR*Gl` into a file on my hard drive, and I import it later in another program and assign it the name `GA`, I want that, if I assign further `GR = 2` and `Gl = 3`, `GA` to be equal to `2*3 = 6`. In other words, I want to be able to use it for further mathematical computation, as I would do directly in the original program.

Which commands should I use for that? I am not finding how to do this very simple thing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to save your expression as a text file, read the text file back in as a string, then convert the string to an expression using ToExpression[], as below.  Is ToExpression[] the function you were seeking?  The two //FullForm's are not necessary, of course, but they show how the string is converted to a Wolfram Language expression for a multiplication using the Times[] function.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I needed! Thanks, that's great!